# Codeigniter active record class (select-from-where)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to make codeigniter filter form work. For example, if "Samsung" will be selected from dropdown list and "2G" from checkbox fields, rows with id 1 and 4 should be returned. But my model returns empty array.Please help me.

**Here is my database table:**

[image: database table]

**Here is my filter form:**

[image: filter form]

**Here is My Model:**

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Model_example extends CI_Model {

      function __construct()
     { 
       parent::__construct();
     }

    public function did_filter() {


   $types = $this->input->post('types');

        $data = array(
            '2g' => 0,
                '3g' => 0,
                '4g' => 0,                
                     );                  
        foreach ($types as $type) {
                                       $data[$type] == 1;
                                  }
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_example');
$this->db->where('phone', $this->input->post('phone'));
$this->db->where((
    (('2g' == 1) AND ($data['2g'] == 1)) OR
    (('3g' == 1) AND ($data['3g'] == 1)) OR  
    (('4g' == 1) AND ($data['4g'] == 1))
    ),NULL, FALSE );
       if (
       $query = $this->db->get())
       {            
    return $result = $query->row_array();
        }
        else {
        return false;
        }
        }  
    }
```

**Here is My View number 1:**

```
    <?php 

             $this->load->helper("form","file");

             echo validation_errors();              

             echo form_open_multipart("example/search");

             echo form_label("Phone:<br>","phone");
             $data = array(
                  "" => "Select Phone",
                  "samsung" => "Samsung",
                  "htc" => "HTC",
                  "nokia" => "Nokia",
                );
             echo form_dropdown('phone', $data, set_value('phone'));

             echo br(5);
              ?> 

             <?php echo form_label("Network Type:<br>","type");?>                   
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="2g" id="types"  <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', '2g', FALSE); ?>/>2G<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="3g" id="types" <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', '3g', FALSE); ?>/>3G<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="4g" id="types" <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', '4g', FALSE); ?>/>4G<br />
<br />          
             <?php

             echo br(1);

             echo form_submit("filterSearch", "Search");

             echo form_close();

             ?>
```

**Here is My View number 2:**

```
<?php 

       print_r($result);
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example extends MX_Controller {

    public function index() { //main function

        $this->load->view("view_example");
    }

public function search() { 

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('model_example');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('types[]', 'Network Type','required'); 

           if($this->form_validation->run()) {

            $data["result"] = $this->model_example->did_filter();


            $this->load->view("view_search_results",$data); 

            }
            else
            {

            $this->load->view("view_no_search_results");

             }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors at all when trying to call `$row->phone` or `$row->network`?

Comment: Yes, I get "Undefined variables" because I have not returned query results in my model

Comment: Your database design is bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: My db design is good and I should feel good. Better solutions will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function did_filter($phone, $2g, $3g, $4g){

   //setup query
   $this->db->select('id, phone, 2g, 3g, 4g')
       ->from('example_table')
       ->where('phone', $phone)
       ->where('2g', $2g)
       ->where('3g', $3g)
       ->where('4g', $4g);

    //execute query
    $query = $this->db->get();

    //fetch result
    return $result = $query->row_array();
}
```

this will return an array of the results.

to troubleshoot use

```
echo $this->db->last_query;
```

and then run the resulting string in your phpMyAdmin to help debug.

also fix your HTML inputs.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="2g" value="1" id="types" />2G<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="3g" value="1" id="types" />3G<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="4g" value="1" id="types" />4G<br />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have just edited my model. Could you have a look on that. Perhaps you can find the mistake.

Comment: your model is incredibly over complicated. you're using PHP to filter when SQL can handle this job by itself. what you see in my answer is all you need for your model. it will return an array of matching rows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have just edited my code in the way you described but it did not work. For example when I select "Samsung" from dropdown list and "2G" from checkbox fields, it should display rows number 1 and 4 from my table but it displays just Array(). Could you please check what can be the problem.

Comment: you're going to have to fix your HTML input names and values as well to correspond to your DB values. see edit to answer.

Comment: the problem is that I should validate checkbox fields as an array (types[]) so that at least one field should be selected (>=1).

Comment: oops. do NOT use the old answer I had up here. NEVER get post data in your model. pass it in with your controller. you can use the array input if you'd like, just map it to the appropriate model parameters.

Comment: could you help me to do it with array? for example, if the user selects "Samsung" and "2G", the array (1,0,0) will be passed to model. Model will check all the rows for Samsung, and if it will find the value "1" for 2G field, it will return that row. In this example, rows number 1 and 4 should be returned.

Comment: no, u pass individual variables to the model, not an array. so call `$this->Model_example->did_filter('samsung', 1, 0, 0);` this part should be easy enough

Comment: the problem is that I cannot pass an array with checkbox values to model, compare with db values and return the result. Could you write that part of code please. I am trying to make this filter form work for several days but I still cannot get the result I want.

Comment: SO is not here to write code for you. we are here to help you debug. i have written a model for you that takes four simple parameters and returns an array of db info. you should be able to figure out how to pass in your variables to it. if not I suggest you go find a bunch more php tutorials because that is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: sorry to inform you that your code is not working, I will try to write the code in my way. thanks for your efforts.

Comment: the model i wrote you is perfectly fine. next time distill your problem down to one issue, rather than asking SO to fix all your problems for you. most people won't waste as much time on stuff like this. i would also suggest going through some basic tutorials before coming on here, so you can get a better grasp of PHP. http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11 is good.

Comment: 1) thanks for the link but I have already watched all the 200 videos, 2)your model cannot be used for my case, because when the user will select field "2G" only row number one will be returned, 3) Thanks for your efforts, I will try to make it work in my way

Comment: substitute `row_array()` with `result_array()` for more than one record